# Run process at startup on Express JS

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to run a process at startup on Express.js?
I want to run a continuous process that will execute every 30 minutes, but it should run always and start running when Express applications is started.

Comment: Perhaps `setInterval()` and `process.exec()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a cron task in nodejs. You need to set crontab on the server to call a path in node every 30 minutes and then have the path execute the task required.

```
app.get('/cron', function(req, res){
    runPeriodicTask();
    return;
});
```